# Change HREF value based on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attached below HTML & JS. Logic required.

1. if 'rt-check--one' or 'rt-check--one & rt-check--two' or 'rt-check--one or rt-check--three' checked, change a href= '#/Test1'
2. if 'rt-check--two' or 'rt-check--two or rt-check--three' checked, change a href= '#/Test2'
3. if 'rt-check--three' checked, change a href= '#/Test3'

Please give me a solution to change href based on logic required.

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" id="rt-check--one" name="rt-check"> Test element 1
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" id="rt-check--two" name="rt-check"> Test element 2
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" id="rt-check--three" name="rt-check"> Test element 3

<a tabindex="33" href="#/Test1" class="rt-button js-button--down">Next</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#rt-check--one').change(function(){
    if(($('#rt-check--one').is(':checked')) || ($('#rt-check--one').is(':checked') && $('#rt-check--two').is(':checked')) || ($('#rt-check--one').is(':checked') && $('#rt-check--three').is(':checked'))){
        $('a').attr("href", "#/Test1");
    } else{
        $('a').attr("href", "#/Test1");
     }
});

$('#rt-check--two').change(function(){
    if(($('#rt-check--two').is(':checked')) || ($('#rt-check--two').is(':checked') && $('#rt-check--three').is(':checked'))){
        $('a').attr("href", "#/Test2");
    } else{
        $('a').attr("href", "#/Test2");
     }
});
```

Comment: Is my proposed solution working for you now?

Comment: This website is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [@*Mark*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43984035/962734), best in your case would be to use [**`data-*`** attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Then update `href` based on the first `:checked` checkbox:

```js
$(".js-check").change(function() {
  var href = $(".js-check:checked").first().attr("data-url") || 'Test1';
  $("a").attr('href', href)
        // FOR DEMO:
        .text(href);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" id="rt-check--one" name="rt-check" data-url="Test1"> Test element 1
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" id="rt-check--two" name="rt-check" data-url="Test2"> Test element 2
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" id="rt-check--three" name="rt-check" data-url="Test3"> Test element 3
<p>
  <a tabindex="33" href="#/Test1" class="rt-button js-button--down">Next</a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" data-href=""> Test element 1
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" data-href=""> Test element 2
<input type="checkbox" class="js-check" data-href=""> Test element 3
```

JS:

```
    $(".js-check").on("change", function() {
     if ($(this).prop("checked"))
     {
       $("a").attr("href", $(this).data("href"))
     }
    })
```

Comment: You may want to use radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the names to `rt-check-1`, `rt-check-2`, etc. and verify if checked like this - 
`$('input[name="rt-check-1"]:checked')`.